# REST call with install4j

Tags: install4j

I am using install4j and I want to call rest api's from installer.
I have searched documentation for HTTP request action but not able to find, so my problem is, 
I want to sent json with http request using post method, for that I have provided following properties:

```
Request Headers : Content-Type=application/json,
Form data = key1=value1;key2=value2;....keyN=valueN,
URL=http://localhost:8180/ng/app-setting
```

But I am not understanding, how to provide authentication details?.

When I run installer file http request execution is start and ask username password after that error message displayed which I was set in properties, But how installer provide exact error message? Because I am not getting what is exact error or what is response message/code?

Please provide the solution and documentation links.
Also let me know the steps how to provide http request (with REST) POST method with json.

Answer (score 0):

> how to provide authentication details

To set the authentication programmatically, set the system properties `serverAuthUser` and `serverAuthPassword` in the installer.

> how to provide http request (with REST) POST method with json.

Currently this is not possible. I've added this to our issue tracker.

---

**Update 2017-11-13**

As of 6.1, when you set the "HTTP request method" property of the "HTTP request" action to "POST", a "Custom request body" child property is shown. If selected, the "Content type" and "Request body" properties can be configured.

Comment: Is it possible now to use REST and external dependencies (v6)?

Comment: Yes, this is possible since 6.1, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. is it also support external dependencies?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by that?

Comment: I mean 3rd parties dependencies, like maven dependencies.

Comment: No, this is build tool functionality, not something that install4j would do.